# Timer can not run in application run in background

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am using timertask implemented in overall application using extends Application calss and timer tick every second and timer will work perfect but whenever i am run the application in background and see the log the timer run successfully but some time it will stop for execution. so how to do for run timer continue in background application running in continue?.

Comment: Could you please rethink your question and edit the grammar? I cant understand it...

Answer (score 1):

You need acquire [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). Do not forget to release.